# Maximum number of distinct values for bitwise OR

Tags: logic, arrays

> You are given an array with $N$ elements. The values of the elements may be any number in the interval $[0,10^9]$. Define $f(a,b)$ as the bitwise or of all the values in the subarray $[a,b]$. Find a bound on the number of distinct values of $f(a,b)$.

**Attempts**: I have tried to brute force cases to find a pattern but was unsuccessful.

Please explain the reasoning behind your answer. I am a complete beginner.

Comment: Can you think of *any* bound? Do you understand the question?

Comment: Well, I originally thought the bound would be N(N+1)/2. Apparently that wasn't a very good bound. I did get a hint to think about the number of bits that may change in a number when bitwise OR'd, but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: This bound is actually tight for $N<30$, roughly.

Comment: Another simple bound is $2^{30}$, which is also tight.

Comment: Can you credit the original source of this problem?  Make sure to provide proper credit any time you copy material from another source.

Comment: Actually, this question was posted by a person in our Competitive Programming Club group. I do not know the original source of the question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Is that because the maximum possible number of changes in the bits is $2^{\lceil{log_2{K}}\rceil}$ where $K$ is the largest element? Since $\lceil{log_2{K}}\rceil$ is the number of bits in the largest element.

Comment: It's due to the range of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the max value here given is 1e9. Therefore at most log(1e9) bits can be there. Suppose we fix an 'a' and iterate over 'b' such that b>=a. Thus this will form a monotonic function as bitwise OR can only increase the value of the initial operands. Moreover the OR operation can only turn a bit ON from OFF and not the other way round. So whenever the values increases that means a new bit has to be set ON. However for a fixed value of 'a' we can only turn on at most log(1e9) bits. Hence when we iterate over 'a' we can have a maximum bound of O(n)*O(log(1e9)) distinct values. Hence the bound is O(n*log(MAX_VALUE))